# Loopback 4, querying with SQLQuery with postgres connector

Tags: loopback, v4l2loopback

This is how I have defined my repository following very generic example given at loopback documentation:-

```
import {DefaultCrudRepository, juggler} from '@loopback/repository';
import {AModel} from '../models';
import {TimeseriesDataSource} from '../datasources';
import {inject} from '@loopback/core';

export class AModelRepository extends DefaultCrudRepository<
  AModel,
  typeof AModel.prototype.id
> {
  constructor(
    @inject('datasources.timeseries') dataSource: TimeseriesDataSource,
  ) {
    super(AModel, dataSource);
  }
}
```

I was hoping that if do `AModelRepository.execute(sql, null, cb)` it would work. But its giving error - `Error: Not implemented`

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow I got it working by injecting the datasource like this

```
    export class SomeController {
      constructor(
        @repository(SomeRepository) public someRepository: SomeRepository,
        @inject('datasources.timeseries') public dataSource: timeseriesDataSource,
      ) {}
      someMethod(){
         this.dataSource.connector.execute(sql, params, cb)
       }
```

I will edit if I find any better approach. Please feel free to correct this answer.

Answer (score 1):

LoopBack 4 does not support `execute` action yet. We have recently discussed this limitation in [issue #2053](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/2053). See [my comment](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/2053#issuecomment-444854776) for some ideas on how to work around the current limitations. I opened a pull request to add a promise-based `dataSource.execute` API to loopback-datasource-juggler, see https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/pull/1671. Once that change is landed and released, implementing `DefaultCrudRepository.prototype.execute()` will be trivial.

We are welcoming community contributions, it would be great if you could contribute the `execute` implementation to loopback-next yourself. See our [Contributing Guide](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/blob/master/docs/CONTRIBUTING.md) to get started.

Answer (score 0):

In Loopback 4 as of now, the answer above from @Miroslav is working.

I use it like this:

```
export class SomeDataSource extends juggler.DataSource {
  constructor(
    @inject('DATA_CONFIG_SOURCE') private dsConfig: object
  ) {
    super(dsConfig);
  }
}
//in tests
const datasource = new SomeDataSource(postgresConfig);
dataSource.execute(sqlStatement);

//at the end of the tests
await dbDataSource.disconnect();
```